# Rails returning object before its updated using json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using fetch requests to update data in my rails app. The request goes through just fine and the database updates correctly. The problem is when the object is sent back as json it is sending it back as the original object. I put a pry in there and the instance variable is correct after the update but after I exit, it catches another pry thats not there and at that point the instance variable is the original one set before the update. This is then getting passed to render.

```
def update
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
  @trip.update(trip_params)
  #binding.pry
  render json: @trip
end
```

Comment: search `binding.pry` across your app and remove it to get rid of it. One point here, you are not check weather `@trip.update(trip_params)` it was successful or not. Check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#updating-articles how `update` action is written.

Comment: The way it was originally written had an if @trip.update condition before render I just took it down to barebones the more I played with it. The update is definitely successful. There are no validations on this model and if I reload the page the correct data is displayed. I also double checked in rails console. Also, the second pry its hitting doesn't exist. There is nothing in the terminal to show where it is and another one just doesn't exist anywhere. It's like its going backwards to the state before the update and using this original instance variable and then going straight to render,

Comment: Use `@` or `whereami` in pry session to check the source code where the control gets halted.

Comment: Even if you don't have validations you should still always check if the model is actually updated. Don't just assume.

Comment: Yea I checked in the console and the data is updating. I ended up just using Jquery instead of fetch and it works.